# Detect Text and URL separately from PHP string

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using the following code to extrack URL from a PHP string.
But what if I also want to get the text which comes before the URL.

String examples

1. Samsung Galaxy F41 (Fusion Blue, 64 GB)  (6 GB RAM) https://www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-f41/p/itmcdc5e93b44d55
2. Some Other text or product name https://www.example.com/product name and other/id4542j56h4j354

The code I am currently using. (only want to get the first URL)

```
$sharedata="Samsung Galaxy F41 (Fusion Blue, 64 GB)  (6 GB RAM) https://www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-f41/p/itmcdc5e93b44d55"
preg_match('~https?://[^\s]*~', $sharedata, $matches);
$firsturl= $matches[0];
$firsturl = str_replace( array( '\'', '"', ',' , ';', '<', '>' ), ' ', $firsturl);
echo $firsturl;
```

The above code will output "https://www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-f41/p/itmcdc5e93b44d55" from the `$sharedata`. I also want to get the "Samsung Galaxy F41 (Fusion Blue, 64 GB)  (6 GB RAM)" as a seperate PHP string, for example `$maintext`.

These strings are shared data from online shopping apps, like amazon. Usually when we share a product from Amazon, it will contain a product title and a link

Can some one help me the text also ?

Comment: Please, give more context. Where these strings come from?

Comment: @Toto, these strings are shared data from online shopping apps, like amazon. Usually when we share a product from Amazon, it will contain a product title and a link.

Comment: So you are trying to parse HTML? Please, **don't**. Use a parser instead.

Comment: @Toto, you I am not trying to parse HTML! The shared content will be pure text!

Comment: Have a try with: `preg_match('~^(.+?) (https?://\S+)~', $sharedata, $matches);`. Text will be in `$matches[1]` and URL in `$matches[2]`

Comment: @Toto, nop, it gives nothing!

Comment: [works for me](https://regex101.com/r/kjoETR/1) or your string is not exactly what you said.